# Why do .NET Core and .NET Framework have different results for this string method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
string test = "t\"";
if(test.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) >=0)
    return;
```

The if statements here have different result between .NET Core and .NET Framework.

What's the difference between Core and Framework for this?

Comment: Your code should throw an _ApplicationException_ in both .NET Framework and .NET Core... You split a string, and then check whether the split results contain a character that is in _invalidPathChars_. Of course there will be such a character in the split results (specifically the last string of the split result), because you just added _invalidPathChars[0]_ to the string in your 2nd code line. Perhaps something is broken with your test setup in .NET Core or .NET Framework (depending on what outcome is to be considered a "test pass"), i don't know... o.O?

Comment: Side note: Throwing ApplicationException's is considered bad practice (as explicitly stated in the documentation for ApplicationException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, test is very weird, I know. I just grabbed some part I need. Just my focused question is why it's working differently in Core and Framework?

Comment: As i said, i suspect that on either .NET Framework or .NET Core, your test setup is not working. Why? I don't know. It is unknown to me what your unit test setups are on .NET Framework and .NET Core and whether they would possibly differ or not. It is also unknown what your unit test actually tests for. Is the test passed when the exception is thrown, or is the test passed if the exception is not thrown? Too many unknowns and too little information for trying to diagnose or troubleshoot your problem... :-(

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for the comment. I changed the question code simply. other things are not important for me now, just curious why framework and core working differently for the simple string related code.

Comment: With regard to your edited question, this Reddit thread can shine a light on this: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/7a8dp0/why_is_pathgetinvalidpathchars_missing_some/. You should be able to easily verify this by inspecting and comparing the return value of `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` in .NET Framework and in .NET Core ...

Comment: It may happens because new string methods implementation that called ICU. Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus

Comment: The last edit fundamentally changed the question and invalidated some of the comments. If the original question hasn't attracted an answer in over two years, what's the point?